# Is there a way to train a PPOTrainer on one environment, then finish training it on a slightly modified environment?

Tags: neural-network, ray, rllib

I'm attempting to first train a PPOTrainer for 250 iterations on a simple environment, and then finish training it on a modified environment. (The only difference between the environments would be a change in one of the environment configuration parameters).

So far I have tried implementing the following:

```
ray.init()
config = ppo.DEFAULT_CONFIG.copy()
config["env_config"] = defaultconfig
trainer = ppo.PPOTrainer(config=config, env=qsd.QSDEnv)
trainer.config['env_config']['meas_quant']=1
for i in range(250):
    result = trainer.train()

#attempt to change the parameter 'meas_quant' from 1 to 2
trainer.config['env_config']['meas_quant'] = 2
trainer.workers.local_worker().env.meas_quant = 2

for i in range(250):
    result = trainer.train()
```

However, the second training still uses the initial environment configuration. Any help in figuring out how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest one of two approaches

### Create a new Trainer instance and restore from the first

```py
ray.init()
env_config["meas_quant"] = 1    # Assuming env_config is set
config = {"env_config": env_config}  
trainer = ppo.PPOTrainer(config=config, env=qsd.QSDEnv)
for i in range(250):
    result = trainer.train()
checkpoint = trainer.save_to_object()

env_config['meas_quant'] = 2
config["env_config"] = env_config
trainer2 = ppo.PPOTrainer(config=config, env=qsd.QSDEnv)
trainer2.restore_from_object(checkpoint)
# Do whathever is needed ...
```

### Alter the environment directly for each worker

May require modifying the environment to set the parameter you're looking to change.

```py
# After the first training loop
trainer.workers.foreach_worker(
    lambda w: w.foreach_env(lambda e: e.meas_quant = 2)
)
# Do your stuff ...
```

---

As an aside, I would avoid using `DEFAULT_CONFIG.copy` since it only creates a shallow copy of the dictionary, so changes to nested configuration dicts could alter the original default configuration. Plus, RLlib's `Trainer` already deepmerges wathever config dict you pass to it with the default configuration.